# CakePHP Test Fixture doesn't create test records

Tags: database, cakephp, testing

I have a CakePHP TestFixture that imports records from the real database table (into the test database table). However, based upon the CakePHP documentation, it appears that I can also have new records inserted along with the records import. This seems like a totally rational idea, yet it won't work no matter what way I try and structure the declarations.

```
class MemberFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
var $name = 'Member';
var $import = array('model' => 'Member', 'records' => true);

var $records = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1999997,
        'last_name' => 'John',
        'first_name' => 'Smith',
        'member_occupation_id' => 0,
        'zip' => '',
        'age' => 30,
        'created' => '2010-10-17 23:18:15',
        'modified' => '2011-10-16 23:13:48',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1999998,
        'last_name' => 'Jim',
        'first_name' => 'Jones',
        'member_occupation_id' => 1,
        'zip' => '',
        'age' => 25,
        'created' => '2010-10-17 23:18:15',
        'modified' => '2011-10-16 23:13:48',
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1999999,
        'last_name' => 'Dan',
        'first_name' => 'Johnson',
        'member_occupation_id' => 0,
        'zip' => '',
        'age' => 41,
        'created' => '2010-10-17 23:18:15',
        'modified' => '2011-10-16 23:13:48',
    )
);
}
```

I've taken a peak under the hood to see how the record import process works in CakePHP. However, its  still somewhat unclear why this functionality shouldn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

'records' => true means that you are importing data from the table, and thus not the ones you have in your fixture

Replace

```
var $import = array('model' => 'Member', 'records' => true);
```

With

```
var $import = 'Member';
```